# How to make UI-Select selections scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using UI-Select in my angular project and I have a pretty specific problem. I am wondering how (if possible) to add a scroll-bar into my UI-Select.

To clarify, I don't want the scroll on the UI-Select-Choices, but rather the input-box that holds the choices after you have selected them. Without a scroll-bar, after making about 3 choices the input-box starts getting rather large, and I would prefer it if the user could simply scroll through the list of selections made, rather than seeing the expanded box with all of the selections they have made.

I tried adding overflow:scroll, on the UI-Select element, as well as the Div that contains it, however, doing this will put the entire UI-Select directive into a scroll-able box(i.e. you have to scroll down to even see the UI-Select-Choices, whereas I only want the box that contains the values the user has selected to be scroll-able.

Please let me know if any of this is unclear, and thank you in advance for any help.